# HttpPost(url) cann't execute solr delta-import while curl "url" can execute correctly

Tags: java, curl, solr

language:java
solr:4.8

when I use curl access this url, its OK

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8983/solr48/company/dataimport?command=delta-import
```

but in my java program I try the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.execute(new HttpPost(url));
client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
client = null;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: there is no error，when I use Java the delta-import not execute

Comment: I want to use HttpClient to access this url and import new data but when run this code the data is not import.

Comment: You probably want command=delta-import as POST-data, and not as part of the URL when performing a POST. Do you see anything in the log on the server side when you execute the request?

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you. the problem is solved by changing HttpPost to HttpGet.Thanks to your patiently answer,my english is poor though.

Comment: But with solr 3.x, HttpPost is OK too.